# Logica de Distribuição Igualada

Tags: algoritmo

Queria saber se alguém conhece algum algoritmo de distribuição igualada. Por exemplo eu tenho 10 espaços e tenho 4 a, 2 b, 3 c, 1 d. E tenho que distribuir essas variáveis dentro dessas 10 posições igualmente de modo que elas fiquem uniforme, sem haver repetições das variáveis.

---

Exemplo : (A-B-C-A-D-C-A-B-C-A)

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço qualquer solução formal mas se eu fosse "inventar" uma faria o seguinte.
Use um contador para sua lista de variáveis.
Faça um looping na lista, inserindo cada variável na sequeência e subtraindo o contador.

Mas dai acabamos com

```
A,B,C,D, A,B,C, A,C, A
```

para seu exemplo.
Porém se tivermos mais A ficaremos com "pares" de A na "cauda".

Para evitar isso você pode checar se a variável anterior é igual à variável sendo inserida.
Se sim, volte para o início da sequência e tente inserir na posição se e somente sim os vizinhos são diferentes.

No caso de termos 11 posições e mais um A a sequência ficaria assim:

```
A,B, A ,C,D, A,B,C, A,C A
```

Você pode tentar is inserindo randomicamente na sequência também mas de qualquer forma algo que vejo como problematico nesse tipo de algoritmo é a "parada", saber quando desistir. Por exemplo se você so recebe A não há como fugir de ter A,A,A,A,A...

**Edit**

Pensando numa maneira puramente randômica:
Para cada variável atribua uma probabilidade dela ser inserida, de início igual à sua distribuição (no exemplo A tem 40% de chance de ser inserido e D 10%).

Tente inserir uma variável randomicamente conforme sua probabilidade, verifique os vizinhos para saber se é possível. Caso seja insira e ajuste a probabilidade (se eu inserir o primeiro como A a probabilidade de próximo muda de 4/10 para 3/9). Caso não seja possível inserir, atribua zero possibilidade para àquela variável e continue. Caso todas as variáveis fiquem "zeradas" verifique se em algum ponto da sequência você um "split" resolve.

O problema não tem solução se houver mais de 50% de um variável. No caso das 10 posições é impossível não haver um par AA se houverem ao menos 6/10 de A.

```
A,X,A,X,A,X,A,X,A,A
```

Comment: A condição de parada poderia ser sem posição possível.

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema me lembra o problema de **coloração de grafos**, no qual que você tem que colorir um número `k` de vértices usando um numero `n` de cores, e vértices vizinhos não podem ter as mesmas cores.

Não saberia dar uma solução de cara, mas tente estudar um pouco a respeito desse algoritmo que com certeza você vai achar uma maneira de resolver seu problema: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

Comment: Parecido mas o algoritmo de coloração de grafos sempre tem solução. Esse parece mais com o problema da "discrepância de distribuição"

Comment: Acho que nem sempre o problema de coloração de grafos tem solução. Pense num caso em que temos apenas três vértices e duas cores – não existe solução. No problema do autor da pergunta, também é possível chegar num caso sem solução, a meu ver

Comment: Sim, pensei no problema de coloração de mapas, que sempre tem solução com pelo menos três cores. No caso dos vértices acho que tem sempre solução quando cores > arestas

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo uma solução com **[Permutação Simples](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Permuta.C3.A7.C3.B5es_simples) em Análise Combinatória**.

Primeiro devemos obter a combinação dos elementos, no exemplo: **A<sub>1</sub>**, **A<sub>2</sub>**, **A<sub>3</sub>**, **A<sub>4</sub>**, **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, **C<sub>1</sub>**, **C<sub>2</sub>**, **C<sub>3</sub>**, **D<sub>1</sub>**. Depois basta eliminar os que possuem letras iguais adjacentes.

Bem, a permutação tem ordem fatorial `O(n!)` (sendo `n` o número de elementos) e `10!` do exemplo iria gerar `3.628.800` de possibilidades.

Entretanto, podemos otimizar o algoritmo gerando apenas as combinações que importam, de duas formas:

1. Ignorando uma combinação (e todas as combinações derivadas) se a próxima letra repete a atual. Por exemplo, se estamos montando uma combinação e temos `A`, iremos pular a combinação `AA` e todas as derivações dela (`AAB`, `AAC`, ...).
2. Ignorando as iterações com letras repetidas. Apesar de termos 4 letras **A**, não precisamos testar as combinações começando com todas elas. Somente precisamos testar um elemento correspondente a cada letra.

Pra falar a verdade eu não sei fazer a análise da ordem de complexidade dessa otimização, mas o que posso dizer é que quanto mais itens repetidos houverem, menos possibilidades serão testadas e mais rápido obteremos o resultado.

Sendo `m` a quantidade letras (ignorando a repetição) e `n` o número total de elementos (contando os repetidos), podemos dizer que, no pior caso, se tivermos um elemento de cada letra (`m == n)`, o algoritmo será efetivamente `O(n!)`. Porém, se tivermos repetição (`m < n`), a complexidade será maior que `O(m!)` e menor que `O(n!)`.

Fiz a seguinte implementação em Java:

```js
public class Distribuicao {

    private List<String> combinacoes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> becos = new ArrayList<String>();
    private long combinacoesTestadas = 0;

    /**
     * Começa pegando as letras uma a uma e combinando o restante.
     * Note que assim já não precisamos verificar as combinações repetidas,
     * já que usamos a chave única do mapa. 
     */
    public Distribuicao(HashMap<Character, Integer> itens) {
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> e : itens.entrySet()) {
            trocarECombinar(itens, e, "");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Procura novas combinações, ignorando se repetir a letras
     */
    private void combinar(HashMap<Character, Integer> itens, String prefixo) {
        Character ultimo = prefixo.charAt(prefixo.length() - 1);
        boolean itensSobrando = false;
        boolean encontrouNovaPossibilidade = false;
        //verifica cada letra, sem repetir
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> e : itens.entrySet()) {
            //verifica se ainda há um elemento disponível da letra
            if (e.getValue() > 0) {
                itensSobrando = true;
                //verifica se é igual à anterior
                if (!e.getKey().equals(ultimo)) {
                    encontrouNovaPossibilidade = true;
                    //tenta uma nova combinação com a letra atual
                    trocarECombinar(itens, e, prefixo);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!itensSobrando) {
            combinacoesTestadas++;
            combinacoes.add(prefixo);
        } else if (!encontrouNovaPossibilidade) {
            combinacoesTestadas++;
            becos.add("[prefixo = " + prefixo + ", resto = " + itens + "]");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decrementa a letra usada, acrescenta a atual no prefixo
     * e tenta recursivamente uma nova combinação 
     */
    private void trocarECombinar(
            HashMap<Character, Integer> itens,
            Entry<Character, Integer> e,
            String prefixo) {
        e.setValue(e.getValue() - 1);
        combinar(itens, prefixo + e.getKey().toString());
        e.setValue(e.getValue() + 1);
    }

    public List<String> getCombinacoes() {
        return combinacoes;
    }

    public List<String> getBecos() {
        return becos;
    }

    public long getCombinacoesTestadas() {
        return combinacoesTestadas;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //prepara o mapa de teste
        HashMap<Character, Integer> mapa = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        mapa.put('A', 4);
        mapa.put('B', 2);
        mapa.put('C', 3);
        mapa.put('D', 1);

        //executa a distribuição
        Distribuicao d = new Distribuicao(mapa);

        //quantidade de combinações testadas
        System.out.println("Combinações testadas: " + d.getCombinacoesTestadas());

        //combinações encontradas 
        System.out.println("Combinações encontradas: " + d.getCombinacoes().size());
        for (String combinacao : d.getCombinacoes()) {
            System.out.println("  -> " + combinacao);
        }

        //combinações onde não houve como continuar     
        System.out.println("Becos sem saída: " + d.getBecos().size());
        for (String beco : d.getBecos()) {
            System.out.println("  -> " + beco);
        }

    }

}
```

No exemplo, temos `n = 10` e `m = 4`. Isso é consistente com o retorno do algoritmo:

- `1074` combinações
- `462` "becos sem saída", isto é, situações onde não havia letras disponíveis para continuar e o processo foi interrompido